# White splash screen

Tags: ionic-framework, splash-screen

How to remove default white splash screen from ionic project. I want my splash screen (which is page) to be the splash screen of my project. I tried almost everything which is available on internet. But nothing worked. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In your project folder, go to the resources directory.

To change the default splash screen, you need to change the file `splash.png` by your image. Don't forget to resize your omg (2732*2732) and to rename to `splash.png`
After the change, just update your project :
`ionic cordova resources`

Comment: I don't want to use ionic's default splash screen at all. I want to use my own customised splash screen, which is a page. I am loading a few data in that, that's why it just can't be an image.

Comment: So its not a splashScreen , u can't load a page just after u launch app, you need to wait the app load.

Comment: Did you try  this ? https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/generate-a-custom-spash-screen-and-icons-in-ionic/

Comment: can't we remove the splash from project?

Comment: Did you try to add this on your config ?   `<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="false"/>` and if it don't work try this : `ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-splashscreen`